# Regex to find exactly X lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to run some regex in python to drop different patterns of text into different files.  Turns out, 99+% of all the lines from my source file have a 3-line format like this:

```
12340987  some other text
          some text
          some text
```

But then I've got small likelihood that the pattern will have four lines, like this:

```
123456789   Some text
            Some text
            some text
            one extra line of text
```

I was trying to write a regex to chase down all the 4-line patterns, and started out with this:

```
^[0-9]+([\s\S]*?)(?=^[0-9])
```

How can I build something with a gist like this, but only grab the 4-line pattern?  Thanks for reading, and helping if you can.  :)

Comment: Consider the fact that you have one line that starts with a number, followed by three lines that start with whitespace. You can just replicate your pattern for the whitespace-starting line three times, or qualify it with a `{3}`. Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Also, do not forget the `re.MULTILINE` option.

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/5ZGXPs/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
^[0-9]+.+$\s(?:^(?!\d).+$\s?){3}
```

flags `gm` set

see here https://regex101.com/r/TOoCzF/1

Explanation:
`^[0-9]+.+$\s` = Start of line, follows by number and then something, end of line and linebreak

then
`(?:^(?!\d).+$\s?){3}` = 3 times a line that does not start with a number

Comment: Great answer, resource and explanation!  Thank you for the help!